# window.addEventListener(load) doesn't include my pop up files

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I have this problem. After I open my pop up a background for this div starts loading eventhough load listener told that the  site is done loading. Does anybody have a suggestion how to include this background file so that the listener tells that the load is done after this file has been loaded?

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
  document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
```

```css
#about .popupBoxContent {
  /*This is the background I'm including.*/
  background: url("about_bg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pop_up.css">

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
        < /head>

  <body>


    <div id="load_screen">
      <div id="loading">
        <object class="logo">
          <embed src="LOGO.svg" width="100%" width:"100%">
        </object >
        < /div>
    </div >

        <!-- About link-->
        < a id = "about_link"
        href = "javascript:void(0)" >
          < img class = "about_icon pop_up_icon"
        src = "about.png"
        onclick = "toggle_visibility('about');"
        onmouseover = "this.src='about_hover.png'"
        onmouseout = "this.src='about.png'" >
          < /a>

    <!--About pop up-->
    <div id="about">
      <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
        <div class="popupBoxContent" 
        style="background: url("about_bg.png") cover" >
          <h3>About</h3 >
          < p > Content goes here.< /p>
          
          <p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('about');">
              <img src="back_btn.png">
              <br/ >
          Back < /a>
          </p >
          < /div>
      </div >
          < /div>
   
   </body >
          < /html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload an image resource by adding a hidden image tag so that it loads as part of the HTML document.  You can ensure your script for your popup doesn't run until this image is loaded by using document.ready().

This won't tell the listener anything but the browser, seeing the same image resource requested, will pull it from local cache and return a response code 303 for the request.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event because the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.